# VbScript Addition Not Working with Decimal values

Tags: vb.net

```
dim a,b,c,d,act
a=86.90
b=12.87
c=0.23
d=CDbl(a)+CDbl(b)+CDbl(c)
act = CDbl(100)
d = CDbl(d)

Console.WriteLine("a : " & a)
Console.WriteLine("b : " & b)
Console.WriteLine("c : " & c)
Console.WriteLine("d : " & d)
Console.WriteLine("act : " & act)

if d=act then
    Console.WriteLine("Passed")
else
    Console.WriteLine("Failed")
end if
```

The above script is not going inside the `if` condition. This issue happening only when `a=86.90`. If `a=86.91,b=12.87,c=0.22` then the `if` condition is satisfied. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Read about floating point numbers here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html. Are you sure wrt the VBScript tag?

Comment: I executed the Above code in the following link. [link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_vb.net_online.php)

Comment: So it's **not** VBScript but VB.NET; but the problems of floating point numbers are (fairly) language independent. So study the link given above.

Comment: Put Option Strict On as the first line in your code.  It will help you to resolve problems.